# Html table - Table in cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, cell

I need to do this in this cell :  [image: Table in cell - Objectifs]

I will give you my HTML now :

```
<TH >Lieu Livraison<br /><br /><br />
                <TABLE border="1" style="width:100%" >
                <TR>
                    <TH style="width:31%; height:25px;">GPS
                    </TH>
                    <TH style="width:79%; height:25px;">Adresse
                    </TH>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
        </TH>
```

My HTML give this :

[image: Table in cell - By me]

But, he miss me only this :
[image: Miss for me]

Can you help me to delete this space, as you can see in my several screenshots please?

Comment: Did you try `cellspacing="0"` ?

Comment: please provide a working example (jsfiddle/snippet)

Comment: I will try this @Dekel

Comment: Did you tried to give a class to `td` and set padding for it in css?

Comment: Don't work too.. @MKB

Comment: Can you share the link where the table can be viewed and inspected?

Comment: @MKB and Dekel : I think, you can understand better here : https://jsfiddle.net/w1w70reb/

Comment: But your code doesn't output as you displayed in the image. try adding `tr` to code and then check

Comment: @MKB : No worries, the second was optionnal for my problem. I just want " stick " cell to anothee (refer to screens in first post).

Comment: add some -ve margin to inner table like `margin-bottom: -18px;`

Comment: It's work @AtalKishore . With your solution one of the two borders pass on the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using table collapse and table borders in your CSS as shown below. I have not done the width, height and colors as it would be redundant. Also, instead of adding an extra table within a table, I have used colspan.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: solid;
  margin: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th colspan="2">Main heading</th><tr>
  <tr><th>Other text</th><th>other Text</th></tr>
 <tr><td>Other text</td><td>other Text</td></tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: @AnthonyMN : Have you look my screens? I have a table in a cell. This table, have two cells again. And I want " stick " this two last cell between the first cell. Look my screens if you don't understand.